# Where to put books while traveling?

Tags: jewish-books, travel, kavod

I am bringing holy books to Israel by airplane. I want to know whether I can keep them in a carry-on bag that ultimately will be put on the floor, at least the floor of the airport, while I am traveling, or if it would be considered disrespectful of the books, equivalent to putting the books directly on the floor, which I know is not allowed. Does it matter if they are sitting on top of something in the bag like a pillow or sweater, or can the bag itself not be on the floor?

Comment: First of all, there might be restrictions on carry-on baggage weight, although a lot of the time they won't weigh it. I don't think they'd be a problem, it's in the bag, the actual seforim aren't in the floor, it doesn't seem disrespectful. You could put it in your suitcase, which might be chucked around a bit, and might make it go over weight, but then you can't use it on the plane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a long and interesting response on the laws of handling Jewish books R Yirmiyohu Kaganoff specifically writes this appears permitted to him, see [here](http://www.yeshiva.co/midrash/shiur.asp?id=23978) where he writes

> Anyone visiting a sefarim store witnesses piles of bagged or boxed
>   sefarim lying on the floor. Are these stores violating the halacha
>   that states "One may not place Sifrei Torah or other sefarim on the
>   ground" (Rama 282:7)?
>
> It seems that this is permitted, for two different reasons:
>
> 1. Most authorities permit placing printed sefarim on the benches where people are sitting in a crowded Beis Medrash. This is because
>      when there is no place to put the sefarim, and people want to learn
>      Torah, it is not a violation of the sefarim’s honor. One could argue,
>      similarly, that it is difficult, if not impossible, for a sefarim
>      store to transport sefarim without placing the boxes or bags of
>      sefarim on the floor, at least temporarily. Similarly, one can contend
>      that while packing and moving, the most secure place to store the
>      boxes of sefarim is on the floor.
> 2. One can argue that the Rama prohibited placing sifrei Torah or other sefarim on the ground only when they are not appropriately
>      bagged or boxed. **Once the sefarim are packed in a respectful manner,
>      it does not show disdain to place the boxes or bags on the floor.**